# Hoe do I stop the program at question number 50 it foes to 52?

Tags: python

In the first loop I want the last question to ask : What is your grade for Vocareum assignments 49-50?
but it goes to What is your grade for Vocareum assignments 49-52? how would i adjust that in my code below?

```
total_point = 0
total_pos_point = 1200
for i in range(4, 53, 4):
    point = input("What is your grade for Vocareum assignments {}-{}? ".format(i-3, i))
    point = int(point)
    total_point += point

for i in range(1, 11):
    point = input("What is your grade for quiz {}? ".format(i))
    point = int(point)
    total_point += point

for i in range(1, 11):
    point = input("What is your grade for hand trace {}? ".format(i))
    point = int(point)
    total_point += point

for i in range(1, 11):
    point = input("What is your grade for mini-project {}? ".format(i))
    point = int(point)
    total_point += point

for i in range(1, 4):
    point = input("What was your score on test {}? ".format(i))
    point = int(point)
    total_point += point


print("\n\nCALCULATING YOUR SEMESTER GRADE...")
print("Total points earned: {}".format(total_point))
print("Total possible points: {}".format(total_pos_point))
percent = (total_point / total_pos_point)*100
percent = round(percent, 2)
print("Percent grade: {}".format(percent))


if percent > 90:
  grade = 'A!'
elif 90 >= percent > 80:
  grade = 'A-'
elif 80 >= percent > 70:
  grade = 'B'
elif 70 >= percent > 60:
  grade = 'B-'
elif 60 >= percent > 50:
grade = 'C'
else:
  grade = 'D'


 print("You earned a(n):{}".format(grade))
```

Comment: So in other words, you're looking to cap out the second value at 50?

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(4, 53, 4):
    point = input(f"What is your grade for Vocareum assignments {i-3}-{i if i <= 50 else 50}? ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were going to re-write your code... this is what I would do:

```
def ask_question_add_points(question, r, points):
    for i in r:
        while True:
            if r.step == 1:
                point = input(question.format(i))
            else:
                point = input(question.format(i-3, i if i <= 50 else 50))
            try:
                point = int(point)
                break
            except:
                print('Incorrect value entered, Please try again.')
        points += point
    return points


total_point = 0
total_pos_point = 1200

total_point = ask_question_add_points("What is your grade for Vocareum assignments {}-{}? ", range(4, 53, 4), total_point)
total_point = ask_question_add_points("What is your grade for quiz {}? ", range(1, 11), total_point)
total_point = ask_question_add_points("What is your grade for hand trace {}? ", range(1, 11), total_point)
total_point = ask_question_add_points("What is your grade for mini-project {}? ", range(1, 11), total_point)
total_point = ask_question_add_points("What was your score on test {}? ", range(1, 4), total_point)


print("\n\nCALCULATING YOUR SEMESTER GRADE...")
print("Total points earned: {}".format(total_point))
print("Total possible points: {}".format(total_pos_point))
percent = (total_point / total_pos_point)*100
percent = round(percent, 2)
print("Percent grade: {}".format(percent))

p = percent
grade = 'A!' if p > 90 else 'A-' if p > 80 else\
         'B' if p > 70 else 'B-' if p > 60 else\
         'C' if p > 50 else 'D'

print("You earned a(n):{}".format(grade))
```